# How to check if all traces of Ubuntu are gone from computer?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, grubrescue, delete

I was tired of my dual boot setup and wanted to get rid of Ubuntu for the time being since I rarely used it. Being the smart guy I am, I simply deleted the partition it was on and added it back to my HDD. Next day I boot my computer up and I'm in grub rescue.

I have the installation disk for windows but I don't have an optical drive on my pc so I tried to solve the problem via grub rescue and Ubuntu Live CD. I repaired grub (sort of) so it booted to a black grub> terminal. (I'm used to purple screen to select OS.) Had no luck with that so I caved and purchased and external optical drive and ran bootrec /FixMbr from the installation disk to fix the booting issues.

Now my question is, with the partition deleted, can I check if all traces of Ubuntu are off my computer?

Comment: are you booting Legacy or EFI?  grub needs to be removed.

Comment: "Now my question is, with the partition deleted, can I check if all traces of Ubuntu are off my computer?" what do you think "deleting a partition" means? :P

Answer (score 0):

Once you check disk management in windows and you do not see any strange non-windows system partitions on your drive then you are good.

And you already said that you did bootrec.exe /fixmbr so then the mbr of your drive no longer contains grub.